iptables issues on Pop!_OS
I am seeing some strange/frustrating behavior with iptables in Pop!_OS, which I am struggling to understand. Firstly, I have a server, on which I want to enable incoming ssh connections. The following set of iptables rules does not seem to work (I can't connect with ssh from a remote machine):
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 434 packets, 243K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  854 85718 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
    5   420 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
  183 27170 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
   75  9853 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
  706  528K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https
 183K  472M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 129K packets, 7005K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination     

However, if I run the following line, the ssh connection from the remote machine does work:
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


Chain INPUT (policy DROP 434 packets, 243K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  854 85718 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
    5   420 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
  183 27170 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
   75  9853 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
  706  528K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https
 183K  472M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 129K packets, 7005K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

This seems particularly puzzling, given that I seemingly had the exact same filter line enabling loopback connections beforehand. Does the ordering of the rules matter in this case?
Secondly, I have the systemd netfilter-persistent service enabled, but it doesn't seem to be saving/reloading the iptables settings correctly on boot. When I reboot, the rules revert to the first example.
Is anyone able to help shed some light on these issues. I need to have incoming ssh connections enabled on the server, and for the firewall settings to persist on reboot.

In this case order shouldn't matter because all the targets are ACCEPT.   You might be able to get some reason for the rejects by adding a log target; -A INPUT -m limit --limit 2/minute -j LOG --log-prefix "FIREWALL: " .  Then packets that don't match any of the ACCEPT rules should cause output that can be seen with dmesg.

@StephenHarris thanks for your suggestion - I will give that a try.
